# Android Glide 4 -- how to compare last-modified headers?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'am trying to use Glide 4. My task is to compare the 'last-modified' header of remote header and the local one. I've seen to *signature* method, but I didn't understand how can I use this in my case.

I used UniversalImageLoader before, and this is my code:

```
        File cachedImage = DiskCacheUtils.findInCache(iconUrl, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());

        MySimpleImageLoadingListener imageLoadingListener = new MySimpleImageLoadingListener(context, colorKey);

        if (cachedImage != null) {
            long modified = 0;

            try {
                modified = Api2HttpClient.getPictureLastModified(iconUrl);
               /* getPictureLastModified() do this:
               httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               httpConn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
               return httpConn.getLastModified();*/
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (modified - 1000 > cachedImage.lastModified()) {
                //remove image from cache
                DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache(iconUrl, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());
                MemoryCacheUtils.removeFromCache(iconUrl, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());

                //redownload image
                ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(iconUrl, imageLoadingListener);

                Log.d(Appspress.LOG_TAG_DEBUG, "old picture detected. ");
            }
        } else {
            Bitmap loadedImage = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync(iconUrl);

        }
```

I didn't find good ways to do the same using Glide. What is the best way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: So Gleb have you found any answers yet? Or did you move from Glide? I'm stuck in the same problem

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil actually, there isn't easy way to solve this, but you can look through this issue: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2805 . The main problem is Glide don't have a possibility to store any data for image (lastModified, for example). Maybe you can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation:

```
Glide.with(yourFragment)
    .load(yourFileDataModel)
    .signature(new StringSignature(yourVersionMetadata))
    .into(yourImageView);
```

In your case, it could look something like this:

```
Glide.with( context )
   .load( iconUrl )
   .signature( new StringSignature( Long.toString( modified ) ) )
   .into( yourImageView );
```

Glide also provides a sample `IntegerVersionSignature` that you could use as a basis for a signature based on a long.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I read this, but I didn't understand something. As I understand, I have to compare remote lastmodified and local lastmodified inside Signature object. But how can I get local lastmodified and remote lastmodified? Okay, I can save lastmidified in signature. But it means that I have to do a redundant head request before the first Glide request.

Comment: You only have to supply the current signature, Glide will handle comparing the current signature with the last one when when deciding if its cache has current image.

Yes, you will have to query the signature before the Glide call. You could probably do that in the background using an AsyncTask or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do additional requests. Is there a way to get 'last-modified' time from Glide directly?

Comment: Why do you need the last-modified date from Glide?

Comment: For example, the request might look like this:

`modified = getPictureLastModified(iconUrl); /*head request*/

Glide.with(context)
   .load(url)
   .signature(new StringSignature(Long.toString(modified) ) )
   …
`
It's OK for cached images, but not  OKfor the first request. It has the following features:
1. I can not do head request before Glide request. I have to download the image anyway.
2. But I have to create Signature for the first request. So, I need to get 'last-modified' header for this.  

The idea to do extra head request is not OK for me, it's high load

Comment: OK. I see. Unfortunately, I don't know of anyway to do what you are looking for and based on this issue: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1847 I don't think it is possible. Someone there recommended storing or retrieving last-modified date where ever you are getting the imageUrl from.